# Xero Integration - API Authentication issue

Tags: api, xero-api

We are trying to integrate Xero API in our web system, however, we are experiencing a particular problem which has not been responded at Xero forum pages, therefore, I had no choice to share it here.

It is a partner application integration and it requires to have some certain files & password within the software.

We have generated the .p12 and pfx files and addressed in the configuration file.

We have downloaded the wrapper solution from Github which is officially supported by Xero and all we did is to change the settings in the configuration file and run the Console App which is named "Xero.Api.Example.Counts" and OAuthTokens.css class throws an exception which is IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 403.7 - Forbidden.

This response is generated from Xero API and we can retrieve more information in detail as "The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes"

The certificates are confirmed by Xero and we are using the correct Consumer Key & Secret in the configuration file.

We have also tried some other simple solution which does talk to Xero API using the partner application that has got the same result.

Is there any advise that you can share with us? Thank you

Comment: I cannot really specify any resolution for this issue, however, the issue is fixed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Install the certificates on your client machine and then use them.

Answer (score 0):

For Partner Application of Xero, you need 
Xero Entrust Certificate - Called Partner Certificate (issues by Xero)
and Signing Certificate - Generated by yourself and registered with Xero.

The Client Machine where you are trying to connect, you need to install these certificates in the Certificate Store.
If it is Windows, you can find instructions to install certificates over here:
[Instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/import-export-certificates-private-keys#1TC=windows-7)